# I can't debugging Xamarin App on Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

Its my first time using an Android Emulator. And I have to debug Xamarin-101 project from Microsoft in Visual Studio 2019 but when I click debugging the emulator opening and showing up on the screen but I can't see the project on the emulator. Can anyone please give me an idea about it? [last screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvDlq.png)

Comment: @Jason thank you for reply i changed the android device to R 11 API 30 and did all the Nuget Updates but I still can't see the project on the emulator Could you help me about it? (I added last screenshot)

Comment: Have you run the emulator Android 11.0? Set the Android as startup project. Check the Build> Configuration Manager. Have you select the Build and Deploy checkbox?